# I keep getting i different time

Tags: java, sorting, time, numbers

Im trying to out put a random number and the time it was generated and sort it but everytime i run it it sorts the numbers but gets different time for each each number after it is sorted.

These were the instructions given 
For this lab you will write:

1)       A “MyNum” class that will generate a random integer number from 1 to 200.
2)      A “Time” class that will return the system time with sufficient resolution to show the time between insertions. I suggest System.nanoTime().
3)      A “Node” class that will encapsulate the integer number and the Time it was generated.
4)      And a “Storage class” class that will contain the all the SORTED Nodes using an insertion sort. 
a.      This class should have a “add” method to add in each node.
b.      And method(s) so the driver class may display the sorted list of nodes
5)      The “main” or driver class.

The driver class should exercise the other classes, such that the MyNum class assigns a number and the Time class a time to the Node class.   The node is added to the Storage class which maintains a sorted list of the Nodes added from Low (position 0) to High( position 49).  The driver class will complete this process 50 times and after completion display all the nodes in sorted order and in insertion order with the time, and the lowest and highest node times.

package lab1;
This is the main class controls everything 
    public class Driver {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[] out = new int[50];
  for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
      out[i] = MyNum.genRandom(); 
  }
  System.out.println("Insertion order: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++)
  System.out.println("Int: " + out[i] + " " + "Time: " + Time.time());
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Sorted order: ");

  Storage.insertionSort(out);

  for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++)
     System.out.println("Int: " + out[i] + " " + "Time: " + Time.time());
     System.out.println("Lowest time: " + "Highest time: ");
 }

}
```

Number class

```
package lab1;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author alpho_000
 */
public class MyNum {

  static Random number = new Random();
  public static int genRandom(){

  return number.nextInt(200)+1;
  } 
 }

Node 
 package lab1;

 /**
 *
 * @author alpho_000
 */
public class Node {

/**
 *@return
 */
static String node(){

   int num;
   long time;

   num = MyNum.genRandom();
   time = Time.time(); 

   return "Int: " + num + " " + "Time: " + time;
   }

}
```

Time

```
package lab1;

/**
 *
 * @author alpho_000
 */
public class Time {

   /**
   *
   * @return
   */
  public static long time(){
    return System.nanoTime();

 }
```

}

Storage class 
        package lab1;

```
   public class Storage {
   static boolean insertionSort;


   public static int[] insertionSort(int[] MyNum){

  int temp;

 for (int i = 1; i < MyNum.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
   if(MyNum[j-1] >= MyNum[j]){
       temp = MyNum[j];
       MyNum[j] = MyNum[j-1];
       MyNum[j-1] = temp;
   }
  }
   }
   return MyNum;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually storing the time that each number was generated. You're printing the current time, throwing away the time, sorting the numbers, and then getting the *current* time again.

You need to add a `time` member to your Node class, and sort Nodes instead of sorting ints. Note that your existing Node class just has local variables, and no actual members. You have to put the variable declarations outside of any methods like this:

```
public class Node {
    int num;
    long time;

    public Node() {
        this.num = generateRandom();
        this.time = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You have problems in all of your classes except Time.